# Multiple Error Messages after exporting excel from php

Tags: php

## **Error Message while opening the file**

[image]

## **Second error message when trying to update the file...**

[image]

**Code in PHP**

```
<?php
    $filename = "test.xls"; 
    
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    echo implode("\t", ["Username", "Order Number"]) . "\n";            
    echo implode("\t", ["wswswsw@s.com", "1234454542122232"]) . "\n";           
    exit();
?>
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: That's not an XLS it's a CSV using tab spacing, and while XSL uses that it also uses other formatting rules you must match, check https://www.knowband.com/blog/tips/export-php-data-xls-file/

Answer (score 0):

This code may be able to assist you in finding a solution to your issue. If it doesn't work as expected, there may be other options that you can try.

```
<?php
    $filename = "test.xls"; 
    
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    
    // Generate the data for the file
    $data = [
        ["Username", "Order Number"],
        ["wswswsw@s.com", "1234454542122232"]
    ];
    
    // Use a loop to generate the rows of the file
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        // Use implode() to concatenate the values in the row into a single string
        echo implode("\t", $row) . "\n";
    }
    
    exit();
?>
```